# AmazonSes SNS bounce notification received only if email notification is also enabled

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, email-bounces

I am trying to process ses email bounce by receiving notification to SQS via SNS.

Configuration           **:**                             SNS notification received
Bounce SNS topic with email notification enabled**:**Yes
Bounce SNS topic with email notification disabled**:**No
Bounce SNS topic with email notification disabled
and email sent to simulator**:**Yes

Please let me know what I may be doing wrong or do we need to keep email notification enabled ?

Comment: Are you using simulator?

Comment: No i am facing this issuee on our staging environment.

Comment: Please share some code and add more context